# Ubuntu - Checking whether a harddrive is unpartitioned, runs an OS, or just a data disk?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, hardware-failure, ubuntu-14.04

I dug up an old harddrive and I want to see what's on it. I don't remember if it was ever partitioned, or if it runs windows, or if it's just a backup disk.

Here is what I've done:

- Plug in disk, Ubuntu **does not** recognize disk and does not automount.
- Open up **gparted**. See this error:

  `Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sdd`

  and then shows up as unallocated 2.73 TB on /dev/sdd
- **sudo fdisk -l**

  ```
  Disk /dev/sdd: 3000.6 GB, 3000591900160 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860531055 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x00000000

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
     /dev/sdd1            1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
  ```
- **sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdd**

  ```
  === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
  Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
  Device Model:     ST3000DM001-1CH166
  Serial Number:    Z1F3ZH6B
  LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0652247c5
  Firmware Version: CC27
  User Capacity:    3,000,591,900,160 bytes [3.00 TB]
  Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
  Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
  Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
  ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
  SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
  Local Time is:    Sat May 21 18:05:13 2016 EDT

  ==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive may be available,
  see the following Seagate web pages:
  http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
  http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223651en

  SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
  SMART support is: Enabled

  === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
  SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

  General SMART Values:
  Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                      was never started.
                      Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
  Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                      without error or no self-test has ever 
                      been run.
  Total time to complete Offline 
  data collection:        (  584) seconds.
  Offline data collection
  capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                      Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                      Suspend Offline collection upon new
                      command.
                      No Offline surface scan supported.
                      Self-test supported.
                      Conveyance Self-test supported.
                      Selective Self-test supported.
  SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                      power-saving mode.
                      Supports SMART auto save timer.
  Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                      General Purpose Logging supported.
  Short self-test routine 
  recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
  Extended self-test routine
  recommended polling time:    ( 321) minutes.
  Conveyance self-test routine
  recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
  SCT capabilities:          (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

  SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
  Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
  ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
    1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   100   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       1452432
    3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
    4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       2
    5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
    7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   100   253   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       146028888090
    9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
   10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
   12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       20
  183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
  187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
  189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   069   065   045    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 29/31)
  191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
  193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
  194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   031   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (0 27 0 0 0)
  197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6h+00m+31.860s
  241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       89828161
  242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       234961

  SMART Error Log Version: 1
  No Errors Logged

  SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
  No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


  SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
   SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
      1        0        0  Not_testing
      2        0        0  Not_testing
      3        0        0  Not_testing
      4        0        0  Not_testing
      5        0        0  Not_testing
  Selective self-test flags (0x0):
    After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
  If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
  ```

  `

This is one of those crappy Seagate 3TB drives with high failure rates (and a class-action lawsuit to follow). **Is this drive just an unpartitioned empty hdd? Is it still in good working condition?**

I'm about to reformat this disk, but I want to make sure I'm not overwriting anything. Am I safe?

Comment: It is partitioned - there is an sdd1 - Note the 1 - and FDISK shows it as having a very large GPT partition.  That looks really suspect to me.  (I'm not posting as an answer though as I'm not sure FDISK reporting correctly - I believe that FDISK does not handle GPT partitions - and this needs to be a GPT partition because its > 2TB.

Comment: @davidgo How can I check what's in the disk? When I do `ls /dev/sdd*` it only prints `/dev/sdd`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are probably using an USB enclosure.

How can you tell?  S.M.A.R.T. reports that the disk is [Advanced Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format) (4096-byte physical sectors), but `fdisk` saw 512-byte physical sectors.  The USB enclosure is revealing 512-byte physical sectors even though this is not correct.  [More details here.](https://superuser.com/a/985330/83694)

I see that `fdisk` could only see `4294967295 blocks`, or `2TiB`.  The USB enclosure may not be able to use more than `2TiB` of Advanced Format disks at all.  I suggest:

- getting a new enclosure that supports Advanced Format or
- plugging the disk directly to your computer via a SATA cable.

---

Some USB enclosures can address Advanced Format but still report 512-byte physical sectors.  If you have such an enclosure, in order to mount this disk, you should get Linux to disregard the incorrect sector size.  Here's one way to do it using a **loopback device**:

```
LODEVICE="$(losetup -f)"
sudo losetup "$LODEVICE" /dev/sdd
sudo partprobe "$LODEVICE"
```

After `losetup` runs, you should have a device called `/dev/loop#`, where `/dev/loop#` is the string stored in `$LODEVICE`.

After `partprobe` runs, you should have a device called `/dev/loop#p1`.

There may be other partitions, which you can find with the `lsblk` command.  The output should look somewhat like this:

```
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
⋮
loop#                         7:0    0  22.4G  0 loop  
├─loop#p1                   259:0    0   512M  0 loop  
├─loop#p2                   259:1    0   244M  0 loop  
└─loop#p3                   259:2    0  21.6G  0 loop
```

If you wanted to mount the first partition on `/mnt`, you could do this:

```
sudo mount "${LODEVICE}p1" /mnt
```

You can then run `ls /mnt` to see what's inside.

When you're finished unmounting, you can disconnect the loopback device like so:

```
sudo losetup -d "$LODEVICE"
```

Comment: When I try `sudo partprobe "$LODEVICE"`, I get `Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/loop0`

Comment: @warchest: Upon checking your `fdisk` output again, I see that `fdisk` could only see `4294967295 blocks`, or `2TiB`.  The USB enclosure may not be able to use more than `2TiB` of [Advanced Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format) disks at all.  I suggest getting a new enclosure that supports Advanced Format or perhaps plugging the disk in via a SATA cable directly to your computer.

Comment: I've hooked hdd directly to my ubuntu desktop (using sata cable) and ran the same commands (except it's on `/dev/sdb` now). I get the same error: `Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/loop0`. I also ran `fdisk`, and this time it printed out `Sector Size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes; total 5860531055 sectors)`. `/dev/sdb1   Start 1  End 4294967295 Blocks 2147483647+ Id ee  System GPT`

Comment: @warchest: If the hard drive is plugged directly into a computer (and not through an enclosure), it is possible that a clone/image of a different-sized hard drive was written to the one you're trying to read.  Alternatively, the partition table could be corrupt.  You can use `testdisk` (`apt install testdisk`) to see if you can rebuild a partition table from discovered partitions.  If you don't find anything of value, you may wipe the disk and repurpose it as the disk itself says it's healthy.