# Recover data internal hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, cable

I have an internal hard disk and I should recover all contents inside it. However I bought a USB SATA cable but when I connect the cable, it wants to format itself but in this way all the data that I need could be deleted. What should I do?

Comment: What file system you have in that hard disk. In which OS you are connecting that hard disk.

Comment: Was the data lost in the first place? Or you just tried to "recover"/copy the data that was perfectly fine as long as the disk was internally connected? One way or another, read [this](https://superuser.com/a/1203621/432690). The point is some disks behave differently when connected via USB due to sector size translation; it's easy to lose the data. You should investigate if it applies to your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the destination PC is stating that it needs to format the hard disk then it's time to be very delicate and look at some file recovery software. You may have to pay for it and it can be used to read the entire disk (as only the partition information may be damaged) and recover your important files and folders.

Additionally: take this as an important lesson in having regular, complete backups of your most important data.

Comment: I'm more inclined to think it's sector translation, as @KamilMaciorowski 's comment above.

Comment: Ooo, I like that link from @KamilMaciorowsk - I have learnt something new today!