# GPT Partition Protective

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

this is kind of very urgent question. My Laptop graphic card died this afternoon , so I opened my laptop and took out my hard drive that contains all of my studies and projects where the deadline is 2 days from now. I put my hard drive in a external case and tried to plug it via usb in my father computer. Nothing happend , drive not showing in "This Pc" . I went to disk manager and I found that my drive is GPT Protected Partition (Windows 10 on both Pcs) Is there anyway to recover the data or how can I access the drive ?

Comment: It may be [this issue](https://superuser.com/a/985330/432690) but the other way around (valid partition table without the enclosure). Or maybe not. Connecting the hard drive directly (not via USB) is a sane step now.

Comment: No frequent backups? I hoped you learned your lesson... You will need data-recovery software to retrieve your important files. Something like: https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/gpt-protective-partition.php, Check the Method #1 section first. Don't try anything else as all the other options will DESTROY your data.

Comment: For somebody threatend by a tight deadline your description is suprisingly thin. Could it be that you your graphic card had a ventilator that stopped, causing overheating affecting your drive as well? You did not specify if your drive started sucessfully in an external enclosure. Using a docking station with an integrated power suppply is a good choice to exclude power supply problems. Even 2,5'' inch drives draw high start-up currents. You did not show maker and model of your drive. You did not tell how the drive was partitioned before the incident. You did not show the current status by

Comment: showing a picture of your disk manager. With so much lack of information a reasonable judgment is impossible and you can get only generic advice.