# Can't mount external USB drive. mount: /dev/sdd1 is already mounted or /mnt/sdd busy

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mount, gpt, fdisk

I'm trying to mount my external hard drive  with this command on my Citrix hypervisor;

```
mount -o rw /dev/sdd1 /mnt/sdd
```

But I'm getting this error:

mount: /dev/sdd1 is already mounted or /mnt/sdd busy

It's not mounted, and doesn't appear to be busy.

```
[root@voice-pool-citrix-3x home]# df -h
Filesystem                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                          2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                             2.0G  152K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                             2.0G  1.3M  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs                                             2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md125p1                                       18G  1.6G   16G  10% /
xenstore                                          2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /var/lib/xenstored
/dev/loop0                                         55M   55M     0 100% /var/xen/xc-install
/dev/md125p5                                      3.9G  388M  3.3G  11% /var/log
/dev/sdc1                                         4.6T  1.4T  3.3T  30% /mnt/sdc
```

dmesg

```
[34823754.643174] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] Spinning up disk...
[34823759.665912] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[34823759.666175] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] 9767475200 512-byte logical blocks: (5.00 TB/4.55 TiB)
[34823759.666180] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[34823759.666597] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[34823759.666599] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 3f 00 10 00
[34823759.666993] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[34823759.667001] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[34823759.667470] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[34823759.764535]  sdd: sdd1
```

fdisk

```
 Disk /dev/sdd: 5000.9 GB, 5000947302400 bytes, 9767475200 sectors

 Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical):
 512 bytes / 4096 bytes 
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes 
 Disk label type: dos 
 Disk identifier: 0x16f2a91f
 
    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 
 /dev/sdd1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
```

The drive does not show up in /etc/mtab

I would be grateful for any support!

Comment: What your `fdisk` sees is a [protective MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Protective_MBR_(LBA_0)). Are you sure the OS can understand GPT? Is/was the drive connected via USB? If [an enclosure interferes or interfered](https://superuser.com/a/985330/432690), it may be the the OS tries to find GPT in the wrong place now.

Comment: I would use plain `mount` to determine what is mounted rather than using `df`, it may be that the os _thinks_ it is already mounted in someway. I would also confirm that `/mnt/sdd` is not linked in someway to `/mnt/sdc` or some other mount point.